# How to sort by greatest and less than in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting

I have values from 200 to 1 stored as strings in an array called beaus.

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dataoflar" ascending:NO];
    [beaus sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

However, this only sorts them by the first number (2 is above 10). Is there any way to sort by amount?

Comment: Please be more precise what type is the value? NSString? or int?, what type is "dataoflar"

Comment: Why are you storing the numbers as strings? Why not store them as numbers?

Comment: It is the way I am bringing in the data. Is there any way to convert them into numbers when they are in an array?...And no, this data has to be brought in by string, otherwise I would change it.

Comment: Then, maybe you should convert string to int first. using : [String intValue];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your sort description like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dataoflar.integerValue" ascending:NO];
[beaus sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

This will get the integer value of each string and the sort will be based on that number instead of the string value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it doesn't matter that the values are NSStrings in the final array you should sort it like this

```
NSMutableArray *mutableBeaus = [[beaus mutableCopy] autorelease];
[mutableBeaus sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];

// mutableBeaus now has the array sorted in an ascending order 1 < 002 < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reasons you don't want to convert the Strings to int during import, you 
have to write and use your own Sorter:

This shows how to sort beause by property "datatoflat" of type NSString which contain number. Sort is done ascending. For descending exchange the last line to `return (i1- i2)`.

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [beaus sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString* s1 = [(NSString*) a dataoflar];
    NSString* s2 = [(NSString*) b dataoflar];

    int i1 = [s1 integerValue];
    int i2 = [s2 integerValue];
    return (i2 - i1);
}];
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have to use strings, then left fill you numbers with zeros, then it will sort like you want with not other changes, like this:
'002' instead of '2' and '034' instead of '34'

Comment: You cannot cast a NSString to an NSUIntger!!

Comment: If you have to use strings, then left fill you numbers with zeros, then it will sort like you want with no other changes, like this: '002' instead of '2' and '034' instead of '34'